# count non-null numbers of an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I am making a method that can count non null value of an object, but I have an object inside another object and I have to confirm if that object is empty too, I tried with isEmpty, isNull but it says it is not empty.

**Object**

```java
public class ExceptionDTO {

    private ResultExceptionDTO result;
    
    private String param;
    
    private String content;
}
```

**Validation method**

```java
 public static <T> void validChoice(Object request, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        int nonNullCount = 0;
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(request) != null || !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(field.get(request)))
            {
                System.out.println(field.get(request));
                nonNullCount++;
            }
        }

        if (nonNullCount != 1) {
            throw new ValidationException(ERROR_MISSING_PARAMS);
        }

    }
```

I have also tried with `!ObjectUtils.isNull...`

Even though the "result" object has no values it says that it is not empty`

**Setter**

```java
ResultExceptionDTO result = new ResultExceptionDTO();

ExceptionDTO dto = new ExceptionDTO();
dto.setParam("param");
dto.setResult(result);

validChoice(dto, ExceptionDTO.class);
```

Here it should not show me "result" as different from null, because so far there is the instance of the class "ResultExceptionDTO" with its null attributes

Comment: When `validChoice` looks at the value of `result` it will see a non-null value. Null is all you check for.

Comment: I tried with !.isEmpty, but it doesn't check it either.

Comment: `isEmpty` of which class? It doesn't appear that `ExceptionDTO` implements any interface with that method.

Comment: What is a "non-null number"?

Comment: Repeating expressions like `field.get(request)` three times in a row should feel wrong to every developer. That’s what local variables are for. Further, since you’re only incrementing `nonNullCount`, starting at zero, the expression `nonNullCount > 1 || nonNullCount == 0` is equivalent to a simple `nonNullCount != 1`. If that’s your intent, use just that. If not, you have to rethink your program logic, as that’s what you’re testing in the end. And if you want to test whether something is “empty”, you have to define the meaning of “empty” first. Seems, `ObjectUtils` has a different definition.

Comment: Further note that you can avoid calling `setAccessible(true)` for each field, using `Field[] array = clazz.getDeclaredFields(); AccessibleObject.setAccessible(array, true); for(Field field: array) { /* your loop body without setAccessible(true); */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method that works:

```
    public static long countNullFields(Object o){
        return Arrays.stream(o.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                .map(field -> {
                    try {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        return field.get(o);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                })
                .filter(Objects::isNull)
                .count();
    }
```